# PostgreSQL insert all the matching columns on NEW in a INSTEAD OF trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, database-view

My question is best illustrated with an example:

Let's say we have **two tables**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE usr_static (
    id bigint,
    dob text,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE usr_version (
    id bigint,
    name text,
    gender text,
    ...
)
```

And a **view**:

```sql
CREATE VIEW usr AS
    SELECT usr_static.id, usr_static.dob, usr_version.name, usr_version.gender, ...
    FROM usr_static
    LEFT JOIN usr_version ON usr_static.id = usr_version.id;
```

Now I am trying to create a trigger function for this view that intercepts an `INSERT` into the view and splits it up into 2 inserts: 1 for the `usr_static` table and 1 for the `usr_version` table:

```sql
INSERT INTO usr (5, '2023-05-11', 'John', 'male');
-- -->
INSERT INTO usr_static (5, '2023-05-11');
INSERT INTO usr_version ('John', 'male')
```

My trigger function would then look like:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_trigger_func() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        INSERT INTO usr_static (
            dob
        ) VALUES (
            NEW.dob,
        ) RETURNING id INTO NEW.id;
        
        INSERT INTO usr_version (
            id,
            name,
            gender
        ) VALUES (
            NEW.id,
            NEW.name,
            NEW.gender
        );
    RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END;
$$;
```

This is a very common pattern in the application that I'm working on. So I was wondering if there is a way to create *one* trigger that I can apply to multiple views?

So my question is, if it is somehow possible to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO %_static VALUES (NEW.*) RETURNING id INTO NEW.id;
INSERT INTO %_version VALUES (NEW.*);
```

Here the `%` would get replaced with the name of the view (`usr` in this case). The tricky part here is to somehow dynamically map the values on `NEW` to the correct table. In other words, without explicitly mapping the columns in the `INSERT` statement to the values on `NEW` as in the above function. E.g. the value `NEW.dob`, would get inserted in the `dob` column on `usr_static`.

I hope I have explained my question clearly.

Thank you so much for any help :)

Comment: From here [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) you could use `TG_TABLE_NAME` and combine with [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Comment: You couldn't use `NEW.*` because the number of columns and their order wouldn't match those of the target tables. Dynamically build the column lists by querying the system catalogs.

Comment: @JohnH what would be the best way to do this? Should I build the query using "string manipulation" or is there some easier/more semantic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's possible to create a trigger function that could be applied to multiple views to perform the described inserts, it's not advisable. A function that worked for the general case would need to query the system catalogs to dynamically create insert statements for each row inserted into a view. This approach would not be very performant. A better approach is to create dedicated functions for each view.

The following demonstates a function that queries the system catalogs to generate a trigger function definition to populate a view's base tables. (This approach can be expanded to handle `DELETE` and `UPDATE` as well.)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gen_view_to_table_trig_func(source_view regclass, function_name text DEFAULT NULL) RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$FUNC$
<<local>>
DECLARE
  created_function_name text;
  insert_statements     text;
  view_name             text;
  view_oid              bigint;
  view_schema           text;
BEGIN
  SELECT v.oid, ns.nspname, v.relname
    INTO view_oid, view_schema, view_name
    FROM pg_class v
      JOIN pg_namespace ns
           ON v.relnamespace = ns.oid
    WHERE v.oid = gen_view_to_table_trig_func.source_view;

  created_function_name := COALESCE(function_name, view_name || '_iotf');

  WITH tables AS (SELECT DISTINCT t.oid AS table_oid, nt.nspname AS table_schema, t.relname AS table_name
                    FROM pg_depend dv
                      JOIN pg_depend dt
                           ON dv.objid = dt.objid AND dv.refobjid <> dt.refobjid
                      JOIN pg_class t
                           ON dt.refobjid = t.oid
                      JOIN pg_namespace nt
                           ON t.relnamespace = nt.oid AND t.relkind IN ('r', 'f', 'p')
                    WHERE dv.refobjid = local.view_oid
                      AND dv.deptype = 'i'),
       INSERTS AS (SELECT FORMAT($$INSERT INTO %I.%I (%s) VALUES (%s)$$,
                                 tables.table_schema,
                                 tables.table_name,
                                 STRING_AGG(FORMAT('%I', ta.attname), ', ' ORDER BY ta.attnum),
                                 STRING_AGG(FORMAT('NEW.%I', ta.attname), ', ' ORDER BY ta.attnum)) AS statement
                     FROM tables
                       JOIN pg_attribute ta
                            ON tables.table_oid = ta.attrelid AND ta.attnum > 0
                              AND NOT ta.attisdropped
                              AND ta.attgenerated = ''
                       JOIN pg_attribute va
                            ON (ta.attname = va.attname)
                     WHERE va.attrelid = local.view_oid
                     GROUP BY tables.table_schema, tables.table_name)
  SELECT STRING_AGG(inserts.statement, ';' || CHR(13) || CHR(10))
    INTO insert_statements
    FROM inserts;
  RETURN FORMAT($DEF$
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION %I.%I() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
      IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        %s;
        RETURN NEW;
      END IF;
      IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        RETURN NEW;
      END IF;
      RETURN OLD;
    END
    $BODY$;
    $DEF$,
                view_schema,
                created_function_name,
                insert_statements);
END
$FUNC$;
```

In addition to matching by column name, it might also be desirable to address foreign key reference columns between a view's base tables. It might also be useful to enhance the `INSERT`s to handle conflicts, especially if some of the columns are associated with a parent table with multiple child rows.